# How can I make it never rain?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't want it to rain in my world, it is annoying and I always have to type `/toggledownfall`.

Can someone please tell me how to make it so that it doesn't rain unless I want it to? Like if I would like it to rain, I would do `/toggledownfall` so that it rains, but I want it to not start raining naturally.

How can I stop rain in my world forever unless I want it to?

Comment: You could install OptiFine and disable the weather there, altough the world has to have Cheats enabled.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think there is no command to permanently prevent rain.

The first solution would be a commandblock with a clock setting the weather to clear.

A way cleaner (though not ultimately permanent) approach would be to use `/weather clear 1000000` which would set the weather to clean for one million seconds (about 11.6 real time days).

Combining these two (e.g. put a daylight sensor on top of a commandblock executing the command should solve the problem. - And would be way less lag intensive than a normal redstone clock.)
Just make sure the commandblock and its trigger are placed anywhere near your spawn or bed so it's probable you visit the place at least once every within 11.6 days.

Comment: I fixed your command. `toggle downfall` does not exist, `toggledownfall` does not have any arguments, and `weather` is limited to 1 million seconds, as per the [wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#weather).

Answer (score 3):

You can download optifine, (You can turn of rain with it, and it's not cheaty). [Download optifine](http://optifine.net/downloads).

You could also turn off particles in the game settings.

If you have commands enabled, then you can hook up a command block (Get command blocks with `/give @p minecraft:commmand_block`) with `/weather clear 100000` to a [redstone clock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clock_circuit). I hope I helped!

Comment: One thing to be aware of (and the _reason_ it's "not cheaty") is that it only disables the visual effects of rain and snow - the mechanical effects [lower lighting, puts out fires, etc] remain in place.